# replacing text on hover using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63utadgw/) demo.

Is there any javascript code to keep changing the 'Z' when hover ?

For eg. when i hover over the Z, it disappears and E takes its position from the right,and E disappears to the left and P takes its place from the right similarly this process continues to form the word Zephyr.

and when the user moves the pointer away. it should come back to Z .

```
.initials {
    position:absolute;
    background:{color:main color};
    background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif");
    color:white;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:60px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look to the code below. Hope this will help you. To increase/decrease speed of animation change the `animate` function's third parameter to your time. Here time is in `ms`.

```js
$('.initials').mouseenter(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        $('.letter:first').delay(500).animate({
                        marginLeft: '-=' + '70'
                    }, 300);
    }    
});

$('.initials').mouseleave(function(){ 
   $('.letter:first').animate({
                    marginLeft: '0'
                }, 1500);    
});
```

```css
.initials {
    position:absolute;
    background:{color:main color};
    background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif");
    color:white;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:60px;
    text-align:center;    
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.letter{
    width:60px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="initials">
     <div class="letter">Z</div>
     <div class="letter">e</div>
     <div class="letter">p</div>
     <div class="letter">h</div>
     <div class="letter">y</div>
     <div class="letter">r</div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63utadgw/16/

Comment: thanks. how do i speed up the animation, and bring it back to Z when the user moves the mouse away ?

Comment: Thanks bro. and finally do i make the animation play completely once on hover. ( Previous example: when i hover over the 'z' it changes up to 'P' and there is a pause.. and then when i shake the pointer slightly, it resumes. How do i remove the pause and make it play continuously when i hover once  Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/63utadgw/9/

Comment: my previous comment ?

Comment: one last thing bro.. how can i add a 0.5 microsecond pause after each letter is changed [ eg. Z -animates to- E (0.5ms pause)-animates to-P (0.5ms pause) likewise ] and the last letter R is not at the center it sticks to the left... :)

Comment: You can use `delay` function to do a pause. I'm seeing all letters are at center. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using CSS Animation. You can see this [How to move text using CSS animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717562/how-to-move-text-using-css-animation).

No need to use JavaScript